# Imageview not moving

Tags: android, view

Im trying to make an Imageview (a ball) move around the layout and bounce a number of times before stoping when a buttom is pressed. The probles is that although the logcat says its happening, i dont see it moving.

Here it is

```
public class BallPhisics {
int x =400;
int y = 0;
boolean bounceX = false;
boolean bounceY= false;
int counter =0;
ImageView object;
public BallPhisics(ImageView i){
    object=i;
}

public void applyMovement() {
    while (true) {
        object.setLeft((int) object.getX()+x); //i know i shouldnt use pixels
        Log.d("EVENT", "X moved");        Log.d("Ended",Integer.toString(object.getLeft()));

        object.setBottom((int)(object.getY() + y));
        Log.d("EVENT", "Y moved");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            Log.d("EVENT", "Time 1 used");
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        if (object.getX()<=50||(object.getRight()<=50)){
            bounceX =true;
            break;
        }
        if (object.getY()<=50||object.getTop()<=50){
            bounceY=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    this.bouncing();

}
public void bouncing(){
    Log.d("EVENT", "Bouncing!!");
    if (bounceX&&bounceY){
        x=-x;
        y=-y;
    }
    else if (bounceX){
        x=-x;
        y=(int)(Math.random()*100- 50 +y);
    }
    else if (bounceY) {
        x = (int) (Math.random() * 100 - 50 + x);
        y = -y;
    }
    counter++;
    if(counter==5){return;}
    this.applyMovement();
}
```

And on mainActivity the onclick event.

```
 public void StartBall (View view){
    ImageView imageview=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    BallPhisics phisics = new BallPhisics(imageview);
    Log.d("EVENT", Integer.toString(imageview.getLeft() )+" before");
    phisics.applyMovement();
    Log.d("EVENT",Integer.toString(imageview.getLeft())+" after" );

}
```

Sorry if it is a lot of reading. By the way does anyone knows the proper way of moving a view?

Thanks in advance

Comment: while(true) and Thread.sleep on the ui thread sono a bad bad idea

Comment: well yes, but this is just an experiment :)

Comment: why please? im not sure. the logcat seems just ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all to move  a View it's probably not a good idea to use `setLeft (int left)` or `setBottom (int bottom)` because this method is meant to be called by the layout system and should not generally be called otherwise, [according to the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLeft(int)).

To move a View dynamically you should take a look at `LayoutParams` or `setX (float x)`  and  `setY (float Y)`, if you can limit your support to Honeycomb (API Level 11).

Regardless which one you use, you may find it difficult to achieve a smooth movement. Therefore I recommend you to use the view animation system to perform tweened animation of your ImageView.

Below you will find an example of a chain animation that moves an ImageView starting from left to right with an arbitrary y-coordinate. After each translation from one x-border to the next, the `onAnimationEnd` will be called and start an animation in the other direction.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  //the ImageView you want to animate
  private ImageView imageview; 

  private Animation mAnimation;

  //The coordinates the view moved to in the last animation 
  private float lastX=0;
  private float lastY=0;
  private float secondlastY;
 
  //Listener that implements a translate animation chain
  AnimationListener animationListener=new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            
            float newY=(float)(Math.random()*0.75);

            //this prevents that we move back to the position we came from
            // to get a more natural bounce animation
            while(newY<=secondlastY+0.15 && newY>=secondlastY-0.15){
                newY=(float)(Math.random()*0.75);
            }
            
            if(lastX==0.75f){
              //test if we are on the right border of the parent
                mAnimation=newAnimation(lastX,lastY,0f,newY);
                mAnimation.setAnimationListener(animationListener);
                lastX=0f;
                
            }else if(lastX==0.0f){
                //test if we are on the left border of the parent
                mAnimation=newAnimation(lastX,lastY,0.75f,newY);
                mAnimation.setAnimationListener(animationListener);
                lastX=0.75f;
            }
            
            secondlastY=lastY;
            lastY=newY;
            imageview.startAnimation(mAnimation);
        }
  };
    
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    imageview=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    //the coordinates the first animation should move to
    lastY=(float)(Math.random()*0.75);
    lastX=0.75f;

    mAnimation=newAnimation(0f,0f,lastX,lastY); 
    mAnimation.setAnimationListener(animationListener);
    imageview.startAnimation(mAnimation);
 }

  //Method that returns a new animation with given start and end coordinates
  private Animation newAnimation(float startX, float startY, float endX, float endY){
     Animation mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
              TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, startX,
              TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, endX,
              TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, startY,
              TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, endY );
     mAnimation.setDuration(2500);
     mAnimation.setRepeatCount(0);
     mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
     mAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
          
     return mAnimation;
 }
```

}

**Note:**
The translation animation is relative to the parents width and height. If you move the View all the way to x=1.0 or y=1.0 you will move parts of the view out of the parent layout. Because it's sufficient for this example I chose to set 0.75 to the max position in either direction. But you should probably set this dynamically in regards to the width and height of your ImageView and ParentLayout.

Comment: Great! By the way, is acceleration a lot of TranslateAnimation or is there a specific method or class?

Comment: There are Interpolator classes which you can find here [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary.html).  You can use them for example to let the rate of change starts out slowly and and then accelerate. simply add something like this to newAnimation function: `mAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());`. If you  want to speed up the movement as a whole, lower the duration of the animation.